# Ways to achieve path finding on android

Tags: android, path-finding

I have spent two weeks on this task and its to no avail,i hope your expertise can help me.

I want to create a simple set of activities that allow the shortest path to be calculated between two points on a tile based map.The ANDROID game /project should allow:

> User to select there starting position i.e tile (x,y) and their ending position i.e tile(x,y)
>
> The path should then be drawn and I want the path drawn to have clickable tiles(which i will assign) so that i can display a popup to the user i.e (you just walked over a golden coin)-i require no score or any of that functionality.
>
> I want the ability to navigate between floors somehow.
>
> I want blockages to be in place(which i set) and  which the algorithm understands and recalculates
>
> Lastly i want the user to have the choice of selecting the shortest path or not.

Can anyone help me on this with tutorials or even provide me with a short example.Its relatively simple I just don't have the skills you guys do to put it in action.I have found JAVA based examples but I don't know how to convert these to android.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Frist try to get Astar working by understanding it. Try to make it as generic in the sense that you can pass any uniform grid in there( 2d array ). Once you have that try to work up adding rules/aspects which dictates where your character can and cannot walk. Do it in steps rather than all in one go. one at the time.

Comment: @sidar excellent advice thank you ...I have the basic understanding for JAVA but im just unsure how to convert it to Android especially with intents etc.

Comment: Android development is pretty much done in Java. I suggest you take a look at libgdx: http://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/ It's free and comes with tons of bells and whistles. It abstracts a lot of concepts on top of the Android API for you so that you can concentrate on your game rather than make most of it from scratch. It can get a bit complex, but in the long run it's completely worth it. On top of that you can export to HTML5 and desktop( Linux, mac and windows )

Answer (score 1):

If you're having trouble with A*, I suggest the following. It talks about the very basics and is applicable for any language/platform: [A* for beginners](https://web.archive.org/web/20171022224528/http://www.policyalmanac.org:80/games/aStarTutorial.htm).

For how to handle click events in Android, please review this: [Input Events](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/ui-events.html)

There are many ways to render graphics. Here are two links which talk about it indepth. [Canvas and Drawables](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/drawables). [Animation and Graphics](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/index.html).

Comment: You should learn how to use comments! ;)

Comment: @jay soyer ok i am having problems rendering the graphics on screen .I have made a plan which will sit on top of a tile but i just cannot get my head around the a star algorithm more so how to manipulate it so when it shows shortest path i can click on scren

Comment: @Savlon I overhauled answer to be less comment like.  Please remove downvote.

Comment: @MarkGaber I gave a general answer to your general question. If you specifically are having issues with your attempt (IE handling clicks), then post code and say I'm trying this XYZ but ABC is happening instead. If you are simply having issues forming your logic, then review the above. If you are still having trouble, you need to backup and try learning Android basics before delving directly into game making.

Comment: @jaysoyer it wasn't me who down voted you lol...